# Update of select after adding data with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

On my view i have  select list like on picture and from plus button its available to add new one. After adding new one the list is not refreshing. If i set refresh on ajax query will refresh all page which i don't want.[image: view]

The button which i add users is

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?modal/popup/staff_add/');"class="pull-left"><i class="entypo-plus-circled"></i></a>
```

the **showAjaxModal** method is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function showAjaxModal(url)
{
    // SHOWING AJAX PRELOADER IMAGE
    jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html('<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:200px;"><img src="assets/images/preloader.gif" style="height:25px;" /></div>');

    // LOADING THE AJAX MODAL
    jQuery('#modal_ajax').modal('show', {backdrop: 'true'});

    // SHOW AJAX RESPONSE ON REQUEST SUCCESS
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(response)
        {
            jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

and this is how i got select in my view file:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="staffs[]" class="form-control multi-select">
    <?php
    $staffs = $this->db->get('staff')->result_array();
    foreach ($staffs as $row):
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['staff_id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['name']; ?>  <?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

View File of staff_add where Ajax Calls:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" data-collapsed="0">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title" >
                    <i class="entypo-plus-circled"></i>
                    <?php echo get_phrase('account_creation_form'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/client/create/', array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate ajax-submit', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('name'); ?></label>

                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-user"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required'); ?>" value="" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('email'); ?></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-mail"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field-2" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('password'); ?></label>

                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-key"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" value="" >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field-2" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('address'); ?></label>

                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-location"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="" >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field-2" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('phone'); ?></label>

                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-phone"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value=""  >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('photo'); ?></label>

                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                            <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" data-trigger="fileinput">
                                <img src="uploads/user.jpg" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px"></div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="btn btn-white btn-file">
                                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span>
                                    <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
                                    <input type="file" name="userfile" accept="image/*">
                                </span>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-orange fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-7">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="submit-button"><?php echo get_phrase('add_client'); ?></button>
                        <span id="preloader-form"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // url for refresh data after ajax form submission
    var post_refresh_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?admin/reload_client_list';
    var post_message = 'Data Created Successfully';
</script>

<!-- calling ajax form submission plugin for specific form -->
<script src="assets/js/ajax-form-submission.js"></script>
```

Comment: What you get on the response?

Comment: its successfully insert query which add a staff to database, why? Or you mean ajax responsee

Comment: I mean ajax response.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @RLam as i put      ` jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);` im reciving HTML response, 
@Ricky i'm already doing this for my Datatables this is select not a Datatable.

Comment: `alert(response)` and see what is coming in alert();

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju as i said in recent comment its coming the HTML of staff_add form.

Comment: if response is correct, then `jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);` is wrong.

Comment: please add the html part of you view where you want to add the response.

Comment: Check the updated post

Answer (score 0):

Try this to load modal html content

```
$('#my_modal').load('path_to_file.php', {attr_id: value}, function(){
    $('#my_modal').modal();
});
```

And put "modal-header", "modal-body" and "modal-footer" tags in that file.